# Automate the Use of the Windows Run Command

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to automate the running of the following commands lines using the Windows Run Command:

```
edismart:C:\EDISMT4\Edismart.exe" "xp[LOCAL]
edismart:C:\EDISMT4\Edismart.exe" "xp[COMMNET]
edismart:C:\EDISMT4\Edismart.exe" "xp[HOSTUPLOAD]
edismart:C:\EDISMT4\Edismart.exe" "xp[HOSTDISP]
```

I am able to trigger the Run Command Window to appear by runnning the following PowerShell command:

```
(New-Object -ComObject "Shell.Application").FileRun()
```

I am looking for an example of how to populate the Open prompt in the Run Command Window.

I am able to trigger the Run Command Window to appear by running the following commands in the Command Prompt Window:

```
c:\windows\system32\rundll32.exe shell32.dll,#61
explorer.exe Shell:::{2559a1f3-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}
```

I am looking for an example of how to populate the Open prompt in the Run Command window.

I tried writing a PowerShell script which uses the Invoke-Command to invoke the run command but did not get the desired results. I have run a google search but have not found any examples to automate the running of the Windows Run command other than the examples listed above.

Comment: I've done it for this post, but please [format your posts properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) in the future.